# wix use custom action to validate text input

Tags: validation, wix

I'm making a installer, and for now, I want to check the user input in a install dialog.

Some said it should use custom action, now I can write custom action in C# and embed it in the installer, then how should I do the input validation?

Thanks!

Comment: To point you in the right direction, you can use your C# custom action to access the value and set a property indicating whether or not you can continue. In you UI you can just reference this property. Also if performance is a priority you might want to write it using VBScript, .NET custom actions are much slower to load and run.

Comment: @codemonkeh hi, would you please give some more advice? Currently I'm trying to use vbscript to define a action, but how could I trigger the action?  the next button and the edit text are in the same dialog, and I want to check the input when click the next button, so the action should be triggered before the click, then how  to trigger it? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to use VBScript to write a custom action you would need to first define it in your Product.wxs, similar to this:

```
<Binary Id="testDatabaseConnection" SourceFile="Scripts\testDatabaseConnection.vbs" />
<CustomAction Id="CA.TestDatabaseConnection" BinaryKey="testDatabaseConnection" VBScriptCall="testDatabaseConnection">1</CustomAction>
```

You then need to trigger it in one of your UI files with a button similar to:

```
<Control Type="PushButton" Id="TestConnection" Width="93" Height="17" X="80" Y="243" Text="Test Connection">
  <!-- Validate the database connection -->
  <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CA.TestDatabaseConnection" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Property="P.DATABASE_CONNECTION_VALID" Value="[P.DATABASE_CONNECTION_VALID]" Order="2">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

And in the script you can set property values like so:

```
Session.Property("P.DATABASE_CONNECTION_VALID") = "1"
```